# Bounding boxes always show height as abs(min.y) + max.y

Tags: three.js

With particular reference to Three.BoundingBoxHelper is this correct? I want to use the numbers to clone and array a collection of objects a number of times in a specified direction. Perhaps there is a better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want `y` but `z` to point up you could consider changing the default up for your `three.js` project by setting `THREE.Object3D.DefaultUp` to `0,0,1`:

```
THREE.Object3D.DefaultUp.set( 0, 0, 1 );
```

Comment: That's great since my objects are related to HTML,  where of course z relates to verticality. Many thanks

Answer (score 1):

A bounding box gives you a couple of Vector3 where you know the minimums and maximums where your object would fit in.

So, yes, the height or Y distance for your object would be:

> abs(min.y)+max.y

Comment: Thanks but why is it Y not Z? Just writing that unblocked my brain! Sorry.

Comment: If you check the vars when debugging your program you'll find a Vector3 named up (I don't remember exactly where). I guess you can use this to define your up vector in your app. By default threejs uses the (0,1,0).

Comment: All OK now I remembered Three uses "right hand coordinate system"